# Regular expression to return results that do not match selection

Tags: java, regex, perl

I work on a product that provides a Java API to extend it.

The API provides a function which
takes a Perl regular expression and
returns a list of matching files.

I want to filter the list to remove all files that end in `.xml`, `.xsl` and `.cfg`; basically the opposite of `.*(\.xml|\.xsl|\.cfg)`.

I have been searching but I haven't been able to get anything to work yet.

I tried `.*(?!\.cfg)` and `^((?!cfg).)*$` and `\.(?!cfg$|?!xml$|?!xsl$)`.

I don't know if I am on the right track or not.

#### Note

I know the regex systems are similar, but I can't get a Java regex working either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?!.*\.(x[ms]l|cfg)$).+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RL4lWC/3)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(?!.*\.(x[ms]l|cfg)$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if any 0+ chars other than line break chars (`.*`) are followed with `xml`, `xsl` or `cfg` (`(x[ms]l|cfg)`) at the end of the string (`$`)
- `.+` - any 1 or more chars other than linebreak chars. Might be omitted if the entire string match is not required (in some tools it is required though).

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this, which matches only if the end of the string isn't preceded by a dot and one of the three unwanted types

```
/(?<!\.(?:xml|xsl|cfg))\z/
```